# DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table <em class="placeholder">file_display</em> already exists

Tags: youtube, drupal-7, media

I am getting this error

DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table file_display already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\includes\database\schema.inc).

While enabling Emfield,Media Youtube and Media Modules. Can anyone tell me why i am getting this error

Thanks in Advance